# TypeScript : Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Issues :

```
error TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'.
error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'never'.
error TS7006: Parameter 'field' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Code :

```
.forMember(
  (d) => d.pageLayout,
  mapFrom((s) => {
    if (s.pageLayout !== undefined) {
      return null;
    }

    if (s.pageLayout !== null && s.pageLayout.length) {
      return s.pageLayout.map((field) => mapper.map(field, PageLayoutDto, PageLayout));
    }

    return [];
  }),
);
```

I am fairly new to typescript, What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript compiler is telling you that because on your first `if` statement you are returning null if `s.pageLayout` is anything but undefined, you can never get to the second if statement with `s.pageLayout` equal to null (nor anything else).

So, because TS compiler is 100% sure that `s.pageLayout` will be undefined at the point where you use it, it won't have the *length* and *map* properties you intend to use. And his way of telling you that is with this "never" type.

Depending on the logic you're going for, an `equals` might solve your issue:

```js
.forMember(
  (d) => d.pageLayout,
  mapFrom((s) => {
    if (s.pageLayout === undefined) { // little change here
      return null;
    }

    if (s.pageLayout !== null && s.pageLayout.length) {
      return s.pageLayout.map((field) => mapper.map(field, PageLayoutDto, PageLayout));
    }

    return [];
  }),
);
```

Although a more simplistic approach might be to only use one conditional statement to check for the existence of `s.pageLayout`:

```js
.forMember(
  (d) => d.pageLayout,
  mapFrom((s) => {
    if (s.pageLayout  && s.pageLayout.length) {
      return s.pageLayout.map((field) => mapper.map(field, PageLayoutDto, PageLayout));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }),
);
```